# Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I run a cuple of virtual ubuntu servers and some of them have kernel 4.15 running while others have only 4.13 running.

On all of my servers I do regularly

apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade

How can I upgrade all of them to kernel 4.15?

Comment: have you tried `apt-get install kernel-image`? followed by the `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 12):

I found the difference.
I had to enable the Ubuntu LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) stacks.

The 16.04 HWE Stacks will follow a new Rolling Update Model as documented at the following location:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

```
apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `proposed` repository to your Ubuntu 16.04 systems with 4.13 kernel:

```
echo -e "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed restricted main multiverse universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-proposed.list
```

Create file `proposed-updates`:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates
```

Open the created file in your favorite editor, let it be `nano` for instance:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates
```

And add to the file this content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=xenial-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
```

Save file and close editor. Update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Find names of kernel packages available from `proposed` repository:

```
apt search linux-image | grep -i proposed
```

Install desired kernel, e.g.

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-26-generic/xenial-proposed
```

Comment: Yes this works, but..... this machine now has /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-proposed.list and was updated to Linux 4.15.0-27-generic x86_64. All others dont have the xenial-proposed.list an run Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64.