# Ubuntu 22.04 and apt upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I run Ubuntu 22.04.1 and as I login as root there is a message saying

```
2 updates can be applied immediately.
```

When I look at upgadeables, I get:

```
apt list --upgradable
libnss-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
libpam-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
libsystemd0/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
libudev1/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
systemd-sysv/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
udev/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4]
```

But when I do apt upgrade nothing happens:

```
apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd systemd-sysv udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Why are these packages are kept back?

And how do I overcome this?

Comment: Does dist-upgrade work? You seem to [do that](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054742/906933) regularly

Comment: Yet another issue with phased updates ...  Also [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them).

Comment: Oh, yes I understand these are Phased Updates! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Phased Updates are a safety feature

Some users get the upgraded packages first, and have the ability to report broken package, instead of everybody getting a broken package at once and millions of users scratching their heads.
It's there for your protection. Don't try to outsmart it.

Kept-back packages due to Phased Updates will automatically resolve themselves, download, and install over a week or so.
Most users should DO NOTHING. It's not broken. Don't try to force upgrades. Just be patient and let the system work.

Diagnosis -- how to tell if Phased Updates is the culprit:

It's easy. Run apt-cache policy  on one of your held back packages. Look for the 'phased' percentage. It's only present if the package is currently phasing.