# Different handling of phased updates in Software Center vs. apt in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, software-center

So in [How to force "packages [that] have been kept back" to be installed [as] "automatic"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat) and [Ubuntu 22.04 and apt upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432649/ubuntu-22-04-and-apt-upgrade) (and most likely a dozen other) they say

> don’t outsmart phased updates

But … if them are not to be outsmarted … why does Ubuntu (22.04) outsmart itself?

- `apt` tells me that packages are kept back
- `Software Center` gets nervous if I won’t start updating **the very same packages** sooner or later
  *“nervous” as in keeping me notified about waiting updates*

I am confused, to say the least.
Why do `apt` and `Software Center` have different ideas about phased updates (`apt` needs to be forced to apply them, `Software Center` just would apply them, when I command `Download`)?
Whom to trust? `apt`? `Software Center`? Both? Neither?

Can anyone give share some insight please?

---

```bash
$ sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apache2-bin libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

$ apt list   apache2-bin libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin
Listing... Done
apache2-bin/jammy-updates 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4]
apache2-bin/jammy-updates 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5 i386
libglib2.0-0/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1]
libglib2.0-0/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 i386
libglib2.0-bin/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1]
libglib2.0-bin/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 i386
libglib2.0-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 all [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1]
libglib2.0-dev-bin/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1]
libglib2.0-dev-bin/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 i386
libglib2.0-dev/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.72.4-0ubuntu1]
libglib2.0-dev/jammy-updates 2.72.4-0ubuntu2 i386
```

Software Center updates:

[image: Software Center Updates]

Comment: Do not understand the question or your statement the the OS gets nervous.

Comment: The use of `-y` with `dist-upgrade` is impressively dangerous. It disables important protections *and* specifically tells apt that it's okay to destroy your system if the logical path leads that way.

Comment: It seems a bug in Software Center. It seems to resemble [LP:#1580833](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1580833). "*Whom to trust*" is apt.

Comment: Indeed, that could be inconsistent buggy behavior. Formely, updates were phased only using the graphical tools. More recently also through apt. Perhaps through different mechanisms, hence conflict. Advice for now: only upgrade with the graphical installer.

Comment: @vanadium, looks like even the graphical tools have different opinions regarding phased updates … so “Software” (with the suitcase icon with square, circle and triangle on it and where the screen shot above was taken) says “OS Updates!”, whereas “Software Updater” (that grayscale icon with the A in it) takes the same course as `apt`/`apt-get` ;-(